# How to know the time taken by expand all and collapse all actions in free-jqgrid

Tags: performance, free-jqgrid

I am using free-jqgrid version 4.6.0, of course it is older. And we have dynamic content for filling in this jqgrid and it will sometime be lesser and sometime very huge as well. I want to measure the time taken by "Expand all" and "Collapse all" actions. Does jqgrid provides any configurations for this?

How can I measure the time taken by these action in browser? I welcome your suggestions!

Thank you!

Comment: 4.6 version of jqGird is just jqGrid and not free-jqgrid. See [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?m=201412)

Comment: @Tony Tomov, Well that's okay. But do you have any idea to measure the time it takes to Expand or Collapse a  grid?

Comment: What do you want to measure? - tree grid expand/collapse or subgrid expand/collapse - it is not clear of your question

Comment: oh, clearly, I am using a subgrid and I want to know the time it takes to expand the subgrid when we click on "Expand all" and "Collapse all" buttons.

Comment: Which type of subgrid is used- Subgrid as grid or simple subgrid? If you give more information (code or demo), then it will be more easer to help you.

Comment: its actually a "Grid as a subgrid" type of jqgrid. But I think, to measure the time it take to expand/collapse a row(or all the rows) doesn't depend on the type of the grid used. But anyway, here is an example fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/8L6xmwcc/4/